# Installing the GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

GeoPandas Installing

When I am installing GeoPandas they show me a error in Anaconda prompt several times. They indicated me **Failed with initial frozen solve** of solving environment. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, I don't know why that happens exactly. But the workaround that works for me is to create a new enviroment with all desired packages listed:

```
conda create --name myenv geopandas matplotlib <other packages>
```